# Alias in Function Declaration overloaded?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have some VB6 code that I am converting to VB.net and came across this section

```
Declare Function TmSendByLen Lib "tmctl.dll"  Alias "TmSendByLength"(ByVal id As Integer, ByRef msg As Any, ByVal blen As Integer) As Integer
'snip'

Function TmSendByLength(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal msg As String, ByVal blen As Integer) As Integer
    TmSendByLength = TmSendByLen(id, msg, blen)
End Function
```

I have not come across the Alias term before but I can guess what it does. What I am unsure of is the reasoning behind overloading the alias. If that is what is happening.

I need to create overloads for the TmSendByLen function as the 'As Any' is not supported in VB.net so I am not sure if I should just remove the alias or if I should leave it in place.

Comment: thanks for the edits Joel. Should have actually read it instead of scimming before I posted it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Alias doesn't specify that the function is overloaded exactly, but that the name specified is really named something else in the called dll.

Since your example is a bit confusing (because of the repeated names), I'll use a slightly modified version to explain:

```
Declare Function TmSendByLen Lib "tmctl.dll" Alias "TmSendByLength" (ByVal id As Integer, ByRef msg As Any, ByVal blen As Integer) As Integer)

Function InternalVersion(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal msg As String, ByVal blen As Integer) As Integer
    InternalVersion = TmSendByLen(id, msg, blen)
End Function
```

So in this modified version, the `TmSendByLength` name is the one that the referenced function's entrypoint is really called in `tmctl.dll`. `TmSendByLen` is what we're referring to it as in our code, and `InternalVersion` is the name of the wrapper function.

I would imagine that this is so that `InternalVersion` can be called across modules/classes, while the `TmSendByLen` version was intended to be private.

To answer the second part of your question, Alias is still available in VB.NET, although `As Any` isn't. (You can find information about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zey12w5.aspx).) Whether you want to remove the Alias or not is completely up to you, but either way, I suspect you're going to need to use `As IntPtr` (or SafeHandle) instead of `As Any`.

Answer (score 2):

The "Alias" keyword in VB6 is *probably* doing what you think it does, however, it's the function name in quotes *after* the keyword "alias" that is the actual function name in the DLL (i.e. TmSendByLength).  The function name after the "Declare Function" part (i.e. TmSendByLen) is effectively the alias that the VB6 code will use.

As you correctly point out, VB6 will not allow the "As Any" parameter type, so from the original VB6 code you posted, the developer has declared a VB6 function which incidentally has the exact same name as the "real" function in the DLL, and altered the parameters to this function to accept only a string type for the "msg" parameter.

The VB6 code as-is isn't actually *overloading* any function, but rather it's *wrapping* the DLL function with a VB6 specific one that constrains the "msg" parameter type.

In VB.NET, since you can't specify "as any", I believe you can replace this with "as object", although that may not be very helpful since other VB.NET calling code could pass virtually anything to this parameter.  What you're more likely going to want to do is to create *real* overloaded functions in VB.NET where the "msg" parameter differs by the type that you want to accept.  This way, you can allow multiple different types, but still maintain some constraints on which types can be passed to the function.

Here's a couple of links that may well help:

[VB6 "As Any" in VB.Net](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/2c87df7c-48ad-4ab8-a6b8-e0e277eb74ec/)

[PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/)