# Does VB6 have a way of specifying function aliases?

Tags: function, vb6, alias

Is there a way to specify an alias for a function in VB6?

For eg. I have the following function

```
 Public Sub printCommonString(CommonString() As Byte)
 ...
```

I call this function like this -

```
 printCommonString commonString
```

Instead of calling the function this way, I want to use a shorter name like

```
pCS commonString
```

So pCS is an alias for printCommonString. Is there a way to write such an alias?

Comment: I've never seen such a thing in VB6.

Comment: Actually, take a look here.  Seems like it can be done:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582187/alias-in-function-declaration-overloaded

Comment: search and replace?? change the original name of the function??? there is no such thing in vb6. and the declare are ment to use with dll so you should compile your function in another place and then get the dll.. and are not supposed to be used with VB dll...

Comment: I also doubt there is such a thing, at least nothing efficient (like redeclaring with the second name and in the body just call the 1st one).  Who cares anyway?  And if you do, then just refine the function with the short name.  Seems easy enough.  Also when you camelcase in VB verbs should begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: No there isn't - thank heaven. The longer name is more readable. If you want to increase your typing speed, use Intelli Sense autocompletion. Type part of the name and the IDE will suggest matches. You can press Ctrl Space to force it to suggest matches. Unfortunately there isn't an autocomplete like in Eclipse, where pCS would be matched with printCommonString (Eclipse has really nice autocompletion for camel case identifiers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to alias in VB6 as far as I've ever seen. Here might be an option if you aren't able to rename the method.What about making a method that simply wraps printCommonString?

```
Public Sub pCS(ByRef CommonString() As Byte)
   printCommonString CommonString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only kind of alias you can use in VB6 are the ones from declaring Function from DLL.
E.g.

```
Declare Function Dostf Lib "stuff.dll" Alias "DoStuff" (ByVal id As Integer, ByRef msg As Any, ByVal blen As Integer) As Integer)
```

Where DoStuff is the function name in the library and Dostf is the function name within the vb code.